# Can I combine different settings for UpdateSourceTrigger in WPF (MVVM) for a TextBox control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, textbox

I have an MVVM application with a TextBox control for which I want to validate that it's not empty. As the evaluation should be performed for every key stroke, I changed the binding so it contains

`Text={Binding ..., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`

Now I'd also like to perform an action when the TextBox control loses its focus, so the default behaviour of the TextBox control would be suitable. My problem is that I don't know how to combine the two settings (if at all possible).

Any idea? How to react to key strokes **and** to the LostFocus event?

Comment: Dou you want to trigger something in your viewmodel when the TextBox loses focus or do you want to handle it in the code behind of the page / window where the TextBox is placed?

Comment: I'd like to avoid having it in the code behind - I need to query a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally implement `IDataErrorInfo` or `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interfaces into your `ViewModels` to handle this in `MVVM`.

Also, `attributes` are really powerful and could probably provide you with a good solution, depending on the requirements you have. It would look something like this in your `ViewModel`.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field 'Range' is required.")]
[Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "Field 'Range' is out of range.")]
public int Range
{
    get
    {
        return this.range;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.range != value)
        {
            this.range = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Range");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I would recommend that you take a look at these articles.

**Attributes-based Validation in a WPF MVVM Application**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97564/Attributes-based-Validation-in-a-WPF-MVVM-Applicat

**Validating User Input - WPF MVVM**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98681/Validating-User-Input-WPF-MVVM

**WPF Validation with Attributes and IDataErrorInfo interface in MVVM**
http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2009/04/17/wpf-validation-with-attributes-and-idataerrorinfo-interface-in-mvvm.aspx

**Using IDataErrorInfo for validation in MVVM with Silverlight and WPF**
http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-idataerrorinfo-for-validation-in-mvvm-with-silverlight-and-wpf/

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [attached behavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) to map the `LostFocus` event to a command in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the `IDataErrorInfo` interface and the `ValidatesOnErrorInfo` property for your binding. A good and simple blog-post on how to use these two can be found here: http://asimsajjad.blogspot.de/2010/08/input-validation-using-mvvm-pattern.html